# Display accents on Touch Bar when holding a letter under Mojave

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, touch-bar

After upgrade to Mojave, a long press of any letter does bring up the accented character menu but not anymore on the Touch Bar (Mac Book Pro 15-inch, 2018 with US keyboard).

Do you have an idea to to get them back on the touchbar ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a possible reason why this may be:

**You've installed the third-party product Webroot SecureAnywhere.**

> Webroot SecureAnywhere is made by Webroot Inc. When this software is
>   installed on your Mac using its default settings, you might notice
>   these symptoms:
>
> Text that you dictate doesn't appear as expected. You don't see any
>   accented characters when you hold down a letter key. You can't select
>   items such as emoji in the Touch Bar of your 2016 MacBook Pro.
>
> Follow these steps to fix the issue:
>
> Click the Webroot SecureAnywhere icon in the menu bar. Choose Pause
>   Secure Keyboard Entry.

Comment: webroot would stop the accent menu from appearing on the screen as well, but hotips says that is still happening.